# Show lines in merged cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, cell-format

So here's the scoop.

I am setting up a form for our office. The boss wants only the fillable cells to be editable. No problem; protect the title cells and sheet structure with only the editable cells being clickable. But there are multi-line, long answer sections. No problem; merge cells, wrap text and voila. **BUT** sometimes these forms will be completed by hand, so.... is there a way to have horizontal lines show up in the merged cells when printed? Or do I have to have 2 separate files, one for printing and lame, manual completion and one for super awesome electronic completion.

Comment: What have you tried? There's the [`Workbook_BeforePrint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195836.aspx) event which may help. Just set the borders before printing?